# Command-Control-Arrow beeps (plays alert sound) in Lion

Tags: macos, keyboard

I've noticed since upgrading to Lion that if I press <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Left/Right</kbd> (and sometimes <kbd>Down</kbd> as well; see below), my computer beeps at me (plays alert sound).

It doesn't occur in all applications:

- In Console, I can press any of the above key combinations, and there's no beep.
- In Mail, it beeps if I press <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Left/Right</kbd>, but not <kbd>Up/Down</kbd>.
- In most every other application, every combination except <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Up</kbd> causes a beep.

I can't seem to find any menu commands that it might be trying to invoke, although even if that were the case, applications such as NetBeans and PhpStorm are the proverbial monkey wrench here:  I have <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Left</kbd> mapped to "go to last edit".  When I press that key combination, my Mac still beeps at me, but it it also does move the cursor to the last edit location.

What does <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Left/Right/Up/Down</kbd> map to that my Mac is complaining about?

Comment: I ended up working around this issue in NetBeans/PhpStorm by changing the shortcut to `Command`-`Option`-`Left`.

Comment: You can also mute like http://superuser.com/questions/98868/how-do-i-disable-the-beep-in-osx-leopard-when-i-perform-an-invalid-action#answer-287085

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The beeping you are hearing in this context is not because those key commands are mapped to something but quite the contrary because they are not.

**Typing an unmapped key command will result in an audible bell.**

As you note <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Right</kbd> in results in an audible bell in Mail.app. You will also note that <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> results in a new message.

So here's a proof to confirm my assertion:

- Open System Preferences > Keyboard
- Select Keyboard Shortcuts from the pillbox at the top
- From the menu at the right choose Application Shortcuts
- Click the small + sign at the bottom left of the right panel
- From the Application pull down select Mail
- In the Menu Title field type "New Message" (no quotes)
- Place your cursor in the Keyboard Shortcut field and type <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Right</kbd>
- Click Add

Now return to Mail and type <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Right</kbd>. A new message will be created but if you type <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> you will hear the audible bell. This is because <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> is no longer mapped to anything. We replaced it.

So when you hear the audible bell it often means that you are trying to do something that is not possible (i.e. typing a key command that has no meaning for the current application).

Comment: Interesting.  That seems to make sense.  Apps like NetBeans and PhpStorm seem to be an exception to this rule, but they do implement their own shortcut handling, so it's possible that they are simply not doing it properly.

Comment: I see the same thing with all the JetBrains apps.  It's driving me nuts :(

Comment: IntelliJ is precisely why I'm here...

Comment: Kind of weird that just because something isn't bound in the System Prefs that MacOS assumes the key combo isn't used, when it could easily be mapped to something important in a 3rd party application, like in an IDE or text editor for example.

Comment: [roNn23's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/260566/98331) fixes the problem in JetBrains tools like IntelliJ, PyCharm, CLion, AppCode, Ryder, etc.

Comment: this ... is not an answer, it's really a comment

Comment: Visual Studio Code has the same [bug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/117934), which the team chalked up to a [Chromium bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=916460) marked as Won't Fix.

Answer (score 25):

Depending on the version of your macOS, you have to do the following:

**10.11 El Capitan through 13.0 Ventura** (from [Adobe/Brackets](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/2419#issuecomment-344351507))

You'll need to create the `~/Library/KeyBindings` directory first. Then create the file `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` with the following content. Restart the app or the Mac after saving this file.

```
{
    "@^\UF701" = "noop:";
    "@^\UF702" = "noop:";
    "@^\UF703" = "noop:";
}
```

**<= 10.10 Yosemite** (Found on [GitHub/Atom](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/1669#issuecomment-135503562))

Create the file `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` with the following content. Restart the app or the Mac after saving this file.

```
{
    "^@\UF701" = "noop:";
    "^@\UF702" = "noop:";
    "^@\UF703" = "noop:";
}
```

Comment: i had to switch @ and ^ on ElCapitan "@^\UF701"

Comment: This answer fixed the problem for me (in CLion and other JetBrains tools) on macOS 10.15 Catalina with no changes.

Comment: Still works in Catalina! But maybe you have to restart the app or the Mac if it doesn't work right away.

Comment: For Catalina and VSCode the first worked for me, while the second did not!

Comment: @philmcole Thanks! I've corrected the answer :)

Comment: The 10.11+ version works on Monterey as well.

Comment: Sigh.  Yet again, Apple makes folks cope with a useless change—no aesthetic improvement and no effect on functionality.  (At least they're not as bad as Microsoft in that trait.)

Comment: Since I always update my macOS only every 5 years (it just gets uglier and uglier :D), I can hereby announce: The workaround still works in Ventura 13.1! 

Comment: You're a genius !!

Answer (score 0):

If you want <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+arrow to also suppress the chime, use this:

```
"@~^\UF701" = "noop:";
"@~^\UF702" = "noop:";
"@~^\UF703" = "noop:";
```

(only tested in Monterey)

Answer (score 0):

If you have issues with control+option+command+arrow as well, then also add these: (tested with Monterey)

```
    "@~^\UF701" = "noop:";
    "@~^\UF702" = "noop:";
    "@~^\UF703" = "noop:";
```

Don't forget to close and re-open the app that you are using to see the effects!