# Typing the control+\ (backslash) on Apple keyboard

Tags: keyboard, terminal

I've been trying for quite some time now to figure out how I'm supposed to type the escape sequence '^\', Control+Blackslash on a Mac.

I have a Swedish keyboard with the Swedish Pro layout, and I have backslash on Shift+Alt+7, but pressing Ctrl+Shift+Alt+7 just gives me a 7, not the escape sequence I would expect.

The closest thing I found while googling is: [How do I send C-/ (that is, control-slash) to the terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24261/how-do-i-send-c-that-is-control-slash-to-the-terminal/24282#24282?newreg=737d4f5dc4054b57ae0e177620eb0d8b)

But it doesn't give away how to do the Control+Backslash, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As a user of the Danish Apple keyboard, I face similar issues. Most of the time I — unfortunately — have to remap keyboard shortcuts through **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts**.
I researched a bit and wasn't able to find the native way to do this combo on a Scandinavian keyboard.

However, you *might* be able to create a service through Automator that presses the keyboard combination for you:

1. Open Automator
2. Create a new document and select **Service** as type
3. Set **Service receives selected** to *no input*
4. Drag out a **Run AppleScript** action from the left pane
5. Replace `(* Your script goes here *)` with `tell application "System Events" to keystroke "\\" using {control down}`
6. Save and call the service whatever you deem appropriate

Then try running it at a time when you need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> (For Terminal: **Terminal** > **Services** > **Name of Your Service**).

I'm not currently able to test this but it might be worth a try.