# Keyboard Shortcut in YouTube Fullscreen in Safari beep alert sound

Tags: keyboard, safari, fullscreen, youtube, alert

When playing a YouTube video in fullscreen in Safari, and pressing any of the keyboard shortcuts, for example the arrow keys, macOS plays the alert sound.

This makes YouTube unusable for me in Safari. How can this be turned off?

This seems to be a known issue: [discussions.apple.com](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250846147), [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/dx3h6x/annoying_error_sound_with_youtube_in_safari/)

This might be related: [Command-Control-Arrow beeps (plays alert sound) in Lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23981/command-control-arrow-beeps-plays-alert-sound-in-lion/), [Mac alert sound when moving forward/backward on YouTube](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/405143/mac-alert-sound-when-moving-forward-backward-on-youtube)